# How do i debug SQL subqueries issue

Tags: sql, subquery

Not sure where I have strayed off course.  I need to pull the color names from a 3rd table to display. Not sure how????

```
FROM CAR_SALES JOIN
     CAR_INVENTORY
     ON CAR_SALES.CAR_VIN = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_VIN
WHERE CAR_CYLINDER = 6 AND
     CAR_AUTO_MANUAL = 'M',
     (SELECT COLOR_NAME AS EXTCOLOR
      FROM COLOR
      WHERE COLOR_ID = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID
            (SELECT COLOR_NAME AS INTCOLOR
             FROM COLOR
             WHERE COLOR_ID=CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID
            )
    );
```

Comment: `WHERE COLOR_ID=CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID(SELECT COLOR_NAME` is not valid SQL. What is `CAR.INVENTORY.CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID(SELECT` supposed to do?

Comment: that has the color Id that I need to use to get the color name from the COLOR table.  I am a beginner here

Comment: No, it's not, because it isn't valid SQL syntax. Read what I asked again - what exactly do you expect `CAR.INVENTORY.CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID(SELECT to do? Read it out loud: WHERE COLOR_ID EQUALS CAR DOT INVENTORY DOT CAR EXT COLOR ID SELECT COLOR NAME AS INTCOLOR`. Does that sound right?

Comment: How can I use the value from the car_inventory table to match a value in the color table, to get the name.  Color (color_id, color_name).  I need to use the car_ext_col_id to get the exterior color and similar for the interior color.

Comment: No need for any subqueries here, just multiple joins.

Comment: I was stumped on how to join a 3rd table.  I did a join to separate out the selected group:  FROM CAR_SALES JOIN CAR_INVENTORY ON CAR_SALES.CAR_VIN = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_VIN WHERE CAR_CYLINDER = 6 AND CAR_AUTO_MANUAL = 'M'

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do two joins to your color table:

```
select 
    EXTCOLOR.COLOR_NAME AS EXTCOLOR,
    INTCOLOR.COLOR_NAME as INTCOLOR
FROM CAR_SALES 
JOIN CAR_INVENTORY ON CAR_SALES.CAR_VIN = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_VIN
JOIN COLOR as EXTCOLOR on EXTCOLOR.COLOR_ID = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_EXT_COLOR_ID
JOIN COLOR as INTCOLOR on INTCOLOR.COLOR_ID = CAR_INVENTORY.CAR_INT_COLOR_ID
WHERE CAR_CYLINDER = 6 AND CAR_AUTO_MANUAL = 'M'
```

Comment: Holy smokes! Thank you.  I owe you a cup of coffee!

Comment: glad to help. BTW there was an extra comma at the end that I just removed.